# Unpermitted Parameter in spite of being included in strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a situation where I am getting the error

```
Unpermitted parameter: incorporation
```

however I have it listed in the strong params:

```
def company_params
        params.require(:company).permit(:id, :name, :employee_stock_options, :options_pool, :state_corp, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :_destroy,
                            incorporation_attributes: [:title, :trademark_search, :user_id, :employee_stock_options, :final_submit, :submit, :_destroy],
                            names_attributes: [:id, :name_string, :suffix, :approved, :snapshot, :company_id, :_destroy],
```

**There's a bit of a catch that might be contributing to the issue:**
The controller in question is actually the `Incorporation` controller.  But, as you might notice, we are using it to create a parent model `Company`, which `has_one :incorporation`.  I realize that this is a bit odd, but I have reasons for wanting my models to be structured this way AND for using the `incorporations_controller` for doing it.

Accordingly, I have my form structured in the following way:

```
<%= simple_form_for @company, url: url_for(action: @caction, controller: 'incorporations'), html: {id:"incorporationform"}, remote: false, update: { success: "response", failure: "error"} do |company| %>
  <%= company.simple_fields_for @incorporation do |f| %>
    <div class="padded-fields">
        <div class="form_subsection">
            <%= f.input :trademark_search, as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Would you like us to do a trademark search and provide advice regarding any issues we identify in relation to the name you have selected?', input_html: { class: 'form-control radio radio-false' } %>
        </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for any insight

**Update:  My `new` and `create` methods are as follows in `incorporations_controller`**

```
    def new
        @user=current_user
        @company = @user.companies.build
        @incorporation = @company.build_incorporation
        @action = "new"
        @caction = "create"
    end

    def create
        @snapshot="incorporation"
        @company = current_user.companies.build(company_params)
        @incorporation = @company.build_incorporation

        if @company.save
            current_user.companies << @company
            if params[:final_submit]
                redirect_to incorporations_index_path
            else
                redirect_to edit_incorporation_path(@incorporation), notice: "Successfuly saved incorporation info."
            end
        else
            render 'new', notice: "Something went wrong; form unable to be saved."
#       render :nothing => true
        end
    end
```

**Update 2: In Case it helps, here are the parameters from the log:**

```
"company"=>{"names_attributes"=>{"145\2853672570"=>{"name_string"=>"test19", "suffix"=>"INC", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "fiscal_year_end_month"=>"", "fiscal_year_end_day"=>"", "street"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "zip"\=>"", "issued_common_stock"=>"10,000,000", "employee_stock_options"=>"false", "options_pool"=>"0", "incorporation"=>{"submit"=>"0"}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

I noticed that (unlike other nested attributes) incorporation does not have the `_attributes` line after it.  Might that be of some significance?

**Update3:** I also seem to be creating an incorporation entry in the incorporations table with the proper ownership assigned.  However no other fields are filled out.

Comment: `incorporation` is not listed in your strong parameters. Try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have `incorporation` in your submitted params anyway - it should be `incorporation_attributes` (as you've already got in your strong params).

--

If you're using [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for), you should expect `[association]_attributes` to be passed as a parameter from your form.

Not having it means you've either **not** got [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in your parent model, or you have not built your child object:

```
#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :incorporation
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :incorporation
end
```

--

```
#app/controllers/incorporations_controller.rb
class IncorporationsController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @company = Company.new
       @company.build_incorporation #-> only needed if a new record
   end

   def create
       @company = Company.new company_params
       @company.save
   end
end
```

---

**Update**

What a strange issue you have - you're passing `names_attributes` fine and yet `incorporation` doesn't work.

The one thing I would say, after looking at your `params`, is that your `incorporation` is only passing `"submit" => "0"`. I don't see what that is; anyway there are numerous issues with your form:

```
def new
    @company = current_user.companies.new
    @company.build_incorporation
    ...
end

def create
    @company = current_user.companies.new company_params
    @company.save #-> don't need to "build" in create
end
```

This will allow you to...

```
<%= simple_form_for @company, url: url_for(action: @caction, controller: 'incorporations'), html: {id:"incorporationform"}, remote: false, update: { success: "response", failure: "error"} do |company| %>
  <%= company.simple_fields_for :incorporation do |f| %>
     <%= f.input ...
  <% end %>
```

When using `fields_for`, you only need to pass the parent object (in your case `@company`). Building `incorporation` will automatically populate `fields_for` without explicitly declaring it.

Comment: Thanks Rich.  I have both `has_one :incorporation` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :incorporation` in `company.rb`.  My `new` and `create` methods have been added to the question above.  I believe they amount to what you have here but I could be wrong.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, let me have a look for you

Comment: I also took a look at the parameters in my log and noticed that `incorporation` is not followed by the standard `_attributes`.  (See additional update above)   Might that be a clue of.... something?

Comment: Well I did explain that at the start of the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, you're right; that was the original premise of your answer.  However, if indeed I'm creating a child properly AND am properly `accepting_nested_attributes_for :incorporation`, ...could it be an indication of anything else?

Comment: Well I've seen singular `fields_for` params not being processed properly - the other issue would be your form itself. I'm writing an update although would have to spend time on your app to see what the issue is

Comment: Gotcha, well I do appreciate you taking a look at this.  At least I know that I'm not missing something terribly obvious.

Comment: Nah, it's always the way, some small issue causing problems

Comment: Your modifications to the view nailed it.  I've actually been chided before for a similar issue.  Many thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, thanks for sticking with it when most would have quit :)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that we need to define this in `company` model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :incorporation
attr_accessible :incorporation_attributes
```

Comment: tags `ruby-on-rails-4` and `strong-parameters` indicates strong-params are used, and `attr_accessible` is..well, not using it :)