# Setting attribute in join model when creating two new parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, join

I have two models: `User` and `Company`.  A company can have many users and a user can have many companies.  As you might suggest, this is the perfect place to use a join table.  I'm actually using a full blown model to join `User` and `Company` so that I can specify the role that each user has.  The table, `companies_users`, therefore has the following columns: `user_id`, `company_id` and `company_role`.

The situation I'm trying to negotiate is one in which I'm creating both a `Company` and a `User` and would like to specify the `company_role` while doing so.

My `new` method is as follows:

```
def new
    @user=User.new
    @company=@user.companies.build
end
```

This creates an entry in the `companies_users` join table but (obviously) does so in leaving the `company_role` blank.

How might I add this bit of info?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2327908)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the attributes through the `build` / `create` methods:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @user = User.new
       @user.company_users.build.build_company
    end

    def create
       @user = User.new user_params
       @user.save  
    end

    private

    def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(company_users_attributes: [company_attributes:[:name]])
    end
end

#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :company_users do |cu| %>
       <%= cu.text_field :company_role %>
       <%= cu.fields_for :company do |c| %>
          <%= c.text_field :name %>
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The above looks complicated, I'll explain in a second.

You need the following models:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :company_users
   has_many :companies, through: :company_users
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_users
end

#app/models/company_user.rb
class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :company
   belongs_to :user
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end

#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :company_users
   has_many :users, through: :company_users
end
```

---

If you want to create a `company` *and* `company_user`, you'll have to pass params for both. Although it looks messy, all you're doing is passing each nested object to their respective models.

If you want to set the "role", you have to pass the attributes to `company_users`. If you want to also create a new `company` (rather than just assigning an existing one), you need to also pass the respective params for that too.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for the response.  I tried deploying your technique and am getting an error, similar to a question you've helped me with in the past (http://stackoverflow.com/q/34807228/2540204).  After following your instructions, I am getting the error `Unpermitted parameter: companies_users`.  Note that this isn't `companies_users_attributes`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Want to go into chat?

Comment: Sure, I just started one here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101868/room-for-neanderslob-and-rich-peck

Comment: Hi Rich, I applied the changes we discussed (adding in the strong parameters, putting `fields_for :companies` under `fields_for` the join table and renamed the model to follow convention).  I am now getting the error `Unpermitted parameter: company`.  I hate to ask again but any ideas?

Comment: Let's go to chat again

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly reference the join table...

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    @company = Company.new
    @companies_user=@user.companies_user.build(company: @company, company_role: 'default role')
end
```